# Timestamp . Different values for the same date

Tags: php

In my MySQL database I have 2 raws with timestamp data type . And I have datepickers in the front end with 2 fields (I am picking values MM/DD/YYYY from   datepicker)  . And when I write my  SQL query using to pull out the time of that 2 timestamp raws  using sql's UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table_name.column_name) and comparing with the same date picked from the date jQuery's datepicker apprears (after calculations) that datepicker's time is 4 hours ahead . How come ? I spent my whole past day not even thinking that could be my problem...
And now to have no conflicts I am comparing mysql's unix_timesatmp(table_name.column_name) with datepicker's time-14400 (4 hours = 14400s) . 
So how do you see an easier way of sorting this out and doesnt this seem weird to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the timezone on the server (which is what MySQL uses) vs. the timezone on your computer (which is what javascript/jQuery uses).

If that doesn't cover it, need more information about what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So to accomplish my  problem need to detect user's time zone ?

Comment: Ahaaa think sorted out . Not going to detect any timezone . Just get the datepicker's value in yyyy-mm-dd format then do strtotime("yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00");

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that was more likely the route you wanted... now be careful about dates that are set within 4 hours after midnight... if it's 2 AM your (client-side/javascrtipt) time, it will be figured one day later than the date in MySQL.  What, in broad terms, are you trying to accomplish with this code?  i.e. what user function is the date comparison a part of?

Comment: In the site I am building  people will be booking rooms . So not relying on user's machine's time I ended up with this function date_default_timezone_set(). Which is really what I needed . The thing I was trying to accomplish is to not let people book rooms if dates  match or overlap with already booked rooms . Thats it. Thanks for caring .